# Enabling certificate based authentication for WCF service using netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, authentication, .net-4.0, x509certificate, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF service which is exposed using a single endpoint with netTcpBinding which sits on **Server A**, hosted on IIS7.5/WAS on our internal LAN on our domain.

This service is then consumed by an ASP.NET web client application sitting on **Server B**, also hosted on IIS7.5 with an external hosting provider outside of our domain, and linked to our LAN via a VPN secured to allow only traffic between **Server A** and **Server B**.

During development while I was testing the concept I ran the web client application on another IIS server internally on our domain using binding security `mode="Transport"` and transport `clientCredentialType="Windows"` which worked fine.

I then moved the web client application to the external **Server B** for further proof-of-concept testing setting the binding security `mode="None"`, as obviously with this server being outside of our domain I cannot use Windows authentication, and it still works fine.

What I need to do now, to enable the switch back to using transport security is to set the `clientCredentialType="Certificate"`, as you cannot have transport security with `clientCredentialType="None"`.

This is where I have started to come unstuck. I seem to be going around in circles as to where in the `web.config` of the service and the client `web.config` to define the certificate and where to store which bits of the certificate.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is authenticate that **Server B** is indeed **Server B** calling the service on **Server A**, thus preventing any spoofing or DNS subversion issues, which could result in the service at **Server A** being illegally accessed.

My thinking is that I need to create a certificate for **Server B** to which Server A holds the public key to validate it? If this is the case **Server B** already has a wildcard SSL certificate installed on it as it serves various applications of ours as subdomains. Could this certificate be used for the WCF authentication?

None of the SO questions I've found seem to cover this, and all the various websites and book examples I've found aren't that clear. It's starting look like WCF configuration is somewhat of a black art.

This is all built using .NET 4 and Visual Basic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011.aspx) has examples of how to configure netTcpBinding with certificates in both code and config. Just pick the scenario that suits you. The certificate should be issued by a public (commercial) certificate authority like VeriSign or Thwate so it will be trusted by your external host provider and your internal server.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not really interested in message security, as it's only point to point transport security would be enough. So I'm assuming I can amend the example linked about to just use mode="Transport". Am I right in thinking that the cert defined in the endpoint behavior of the service needs to be installed on Server A (with the service) and then the cert defined in the client web.config installed on Server B (with the client app)? If the cert is issued by trusted CA do I still need to install public keys on the opposite servers?

Comment: Yes, netTcpBinding can be configured for transport mode only. The certificate will need to be installed on both servers. The hosting provider may want to do it themselves or allow you to install it. The web.config on server B will just refer to whichever cert store the host provider designates for their server.

Comment: OK. The hosted server is a dedicated server with RDP access so I can add whatever certs required. The hosted server does already have a wildcard cert installed which is used for the hosted IIS sites. I'm assuming this could be used for the client application. But then the internal server (Server A) would need it's own cert, and then the public keys from both certs installed on the opposing server? Or is the public key bit not required?

Comment: Both the WCF client (server B) and service (server A) need to refer to the *same* certificate (installed separately on each machine). This [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732391.aspx) shows how your client certificate show be configured for netTcpBinding with transport security. The service would be similarly set up except the certificate would be configured in the serviceBehaviors element instead of the endpointBehaviors element. WCF handles getting the public keys and such as long as it is pointed to the correct certificate.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Let me have a go at setting that up and I'll get back to you.

Comment: OK, after much tweaking of config files and location of certificates I've finally got it working. Thanks for all the help.